# how to implement add to wallet functionality in node js?

Tags: node.js, wallet

I have successfully created pass using passbook module of npm and sending that pass in email but now i am unable to understand how to add that pass to apple wallet? Please help any pearl of knowledge and help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the pass you have created a valid pass?

If the pass is valid, they can tap on the attached pass in Mail and a preview will slide up, giving them the ability to "Add" their pass to Apple Wallet.

If you send a pass in an email which isn't valid, the user will see this when they try to open the `.pkpass` file:

[image]

In order to resolve this, you can [Debug your passes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW21) by dragging them into the iOS simulator and seeing if they are valid:

[image]

Hope that's useful!